# PHP - foreach loop like WHERE clause

Tags: php, foreach, where-clause

I've been trying to figure this one out but just can't wrap my head around it.

I have these xml objects that I'm working with:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [product_category_id] => 13463
        [name] => A Athletic Wear
        [path] => A Athletic Wear
        [thumburl_front] => REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/440/ProductCategories/A_Athletic_Wear/80.gif
    )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [product_category_id] => 13475
        [name] => A Accessories
        [path] => A Accessories
        [thumburl_front] => REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/440/ProductCategories/A_Accessories/80.gif
    )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [product_category_id] => 13482
        [parent_id] => 13463
        [name] => Crewneck Sweatshirts
        [path] => A Athletic Wear -> Crewneck Sweatshirts
        [thumburl_front] => REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/440/ProductCategories/A_Athletic_Wear/Crewneck_Sweatshirts/80.gif
    )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[@attributes] => Array
    (
        [product_category_id] => 13483
        [parent_id] => 13475
        [name] => Aprons
        [path] => A Accessories -> Aprons
        [thumburl_front] => REPLACE_DOMAIN_WITH/images/publishers/440/ProductCategories/A_Accessories/Aprons/80.gif
    )

)
```

What would be the right loop to use so that the final markup looks like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>A Athletic Wear</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Crewneck Sweatshirt</li>
    </ul>
  <li>A Accessories</li>
    <ul>
      <li>Aprons</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Here's my function:

```
function GetCatalogyList() {
  global $url, $get_product_catalog;

  $xml = simplexml_load_file($url . $get_product_catalog . "");

  foreach ($xml as $items) {
    $pcid = $items["product_category_id"];
    $pid = $items["parent_id"];
    $name = $items["name"];

    // Logic to iterate through the xml so that product_category_id elements 
    // appears under the parent_id element using unordered list.

  }

  return $return;

}
```

If this was SQL i'd simply be using a WERE clause and get the rest going. But this one's something I haven't encountered before and need help. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351713/php-simple-xml-nested-hierarchy

Comment: That's the same as in SQL. You fetch a result from SQL query, then you parse that array. The only difference is how that array is being extracted.

Comment: Can you provide an example of that XML document? (not a result i.e `SimpleXMLElement`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first thing you have to realize is that you're dealing with an array, not with a database. A SQL simply returns a result-set as array, and then you just parse it the way you need.

As for you function, it has several problems: You [tightly-couple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) data loading, parsing and rendering (seems so), that merely makes harder to read its function body.

In order to solve a problem like this, you need to break the task into small ones. Here's what needs to be done:

1. Loading data from external resource (be it XML, JSON or whatetver)
2. Parsing that data
3. Rendering parsed data

So in your case, that would look like this:

```
$url = 'http://stores.inksoft.com/GetProductCategoryList/1210/';

$data = parse_data(simplexml_load_file($url));

echo render_as_dropdown($data);
```

And the functions, would look like this,

```
function parse_data($array) {

    // We're going to keep relationships here
    $data = array(
        'items' => array(),
        'parents' => array()
    );

    foreach ($array as $node) {

        // First step - Make those XML attributes easier to read
        $attributes = (array) $node->attributes();
        $attributes = $attributes['@attributes'];


        $data['items'][$attributes['product_category_id']] = $attributes;

        // When we have no parents, let's make it null to avoid conflicts
        if (!isset($attributes['parent_id'])) {
            $attributes['parent_id'] = null;
        }

        $data['parents'][$attributes['parent_id']][] = $attributes['product_category_id']; 
    }

    return $data;
}


function render_as_dropdown($data, $parentId = null) {
    $html = ''; 

    if (isset($data['parents'][$parentId])) {

        $html = '<ul>'; 

        foreach ($data['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId) {

            $html .= '<li><a href="#">' . $data['items'][$itemId]['name'] . '</a>'; 

            // find childitems recursively 
            $html .= render_as_dropdown($data, $itemId); 
            $html .= '</li>'; 
        }

        $html .= '</ul>'; 
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. This thing is called **Adjacency list model** and it's basically used to make unlimited product category deeps, and for making drop-down menus right from CMS. I just adopter it for your situation. If you wanna learn more, have a look at: www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

Comment: Still looking at the code. Still baffled. You basically took the entire feed and restructured it into custom array, and then topped it off by using a neat recursive function. Im getting this one engraved :)

Comment: Believe me, I've been dealing with this for quite long time. That's the only clear way to solve this problem. What you can improve is to turn that stuff into OOP, but the concepts remains the same. As for improving loading time from external resource, you can use `curl` and then load it as a string via `simplexml_load_string()`

Comment: How would curl improve loading in this regard? The simplexml function is already hitting a page with raw data so there's not much to process. Just wondering. Thanks.

Comment: `simplexml_load_file($url)` is a equivalent to `simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url))`. There are lot of discussion around the web `file_get_contents() vs. curl` to fetch data. See this one for example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/24954327/1208233

Comment: Interesting. I'll give that a shot and monitor response time difference. Thanks