# Multi level menu in CodeIgniter with single table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I am trying to create a multi level menu. Below is my mega menu structure.

```
________________________________________________________________________
|    main menu    |  main menu     | main menu
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
| sub menu        |  sub menu      | sub menu

| sub sub menu    |  sub sub menu  | sub sub menu
| sub sub menu    |  sub sub menu  | sub sub menu
| sub sub menu    |  sub sub menu  | sub sub menu
| sub sub menu    |  sub sub menu  | sub sub menu
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

**My Table**

```
________________________________________________________________________
| menu_id              |  menu_parent     | menu_name
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
| 1               |  0             | Root
| 2               |  1             | Sub category of root
| 3               |  0             | category 1
| 4               |  3             | sub category of category 1
| 5               |  4             | sub category of first sub category of category 1
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

**my model**

```
  protected function getCategoryTree($level = 0, $prefix = '') {
    $rows = $this->db
        ->select('menu_id,menu_parent,menu_name')
        ->where('menu_parent', $level)
        ->where('menu_status', '0')
        ->order_by('menu_id','asc')
        ->get('menu')
        ->result();
    $category = '';
    if (count($rows) > 0) {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
                $category .= $row->menu_name . "\n";
                // Append subcategories
                $category .= $this->getCategoryTree($row->menu_id);
        }
    }
    return $category;
}

    public function printCategoryTree() {
        $getCategoryTree = $this->getCategoryTree();
        return $getCategoryTree;
    }
```

My problem is that, i want my Main Menu, Sub Menu & Sub Sub Menu to display with proper css. But as per the above code i failed to manage sub menu & sub sub menu.

So i need to get all values of sub menu & sub sub menu independently. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647633/multi-level-menu-from-database-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

I know a lot of people do it this way, but I believe Table for menu is not the best choice most of the time. It looks like you are just trying to complicate it. I would not recommend to put a Square peg in a Round hole.

I mean when you use table, you are going to have to loose the natural hierarchy and you have to come up with tweaks, hacks and work-arounds to simulate it then loop through to create the actual hierarchy, which is just too much work.

You better use MongoDB or if MongoDB is overkill then just use a simple jSON file to save deeply nested family tree of the entire menu like parent menu, child menu, grand child menu, uncle menu, aunt menu, nephew menu, grand parent menu etc (hahaha lol) everything the way it is.

Comment: Multi level category multiselect CodeIgniter
https://github.com/hamedhossani/Multi_level_category_multiselect_CodeIgniter