# An object in SOAP response is empty when using PHP

Tags: php, soap

I have a strange problem. I'm using SOAP for PHP and fetching prices.

If I use SoapUI to fetch the prices the response looks like this:

```
<article>
   <id>53db51:f984db9fa4:-773c</id>
   <primaryid>BG267</primaryid>
   <isremoved>false</isremoved>
   <articlecampaignprice>
      <currency>NOK</currency>
      <price>340.0</price>
   </articlecampaignprice>
</article>
```

But, if I do the same in PHP, the response I get is this:

```
object(stdClass)#81 (1) {
["article"]=>
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#82 (4) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(23) "53db51:f984db9fa4:-773c"
    ["primaryid"]=>
    string(5) "BG267"
    ["isremoved"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["articlecampaignprice"]=>
    object(stdClass)#83 (0) {
    }
  }
}
}
```

The "articlecampaignprice"-object is empty. Are there any settings in PHP that can cause this? I already have WSDL-Cache set to 0.

Comment: Make sure the `XML` mentioned in this post is the actual `XML` you are getting.

Comment: Can you show the PHP your using?

Comment: how you are converting xml into array

Comment: However you're parsing the XML it looks like you're not processing nested nodes. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10351713/851885

Comment: I'm just using var_dump(), to dump the response from the service. PHP 5.5.9

Comment: I don't understand why this question is still here. Should be removed long time ago.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem addresse in the question was with an external service and not with the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?php
$xmlData = "<article>
   <id>53db51:f984db9fa4:-773c</id>
   <primaryid>BG267</primaryid>
   <isremoved>false</isremoved>
   <articlecampaignprice>
      <currency>NOK</currency>
      <price>340.0</price>
   </articlecampaignprice>
</article>";

$xml=simplexml_load_string($xmlData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($xml);
?>
```

> OUTPUT

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [id] => 53db51:f984db9fa4:-773c
    [primaryid] => BG267
    [isremoved] => false
    [articlecampaignprice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [currency] => NOK
            [price] => 340.0
        )

)
```